# LSTM Networks for Sentiment Analysis - How to extend this model to 3 classes and classify new examples?

Tags: deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, lstm

I'm trying the code from this link http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html and have changed the imdb data to my own data. I'm trying to extend this model to a 3-class multinomial model with a "neutral" class added instead of the binomial model provided in the tutorial that classifies only "positive" and "negative" classes.

To build this new model, I rewrote the **build_dict** and **grab_data** functions to build my custom dictionary and return data for the three classes and made the following changes to **main()** in **imdb_preprocess.py**:

```
dictionary = build_dict()

train_x_pos, train_x_neu, train_x_neg = grab_data('train', dictionary)
test_x_pos, test_x_neu, test_x_neg = grab_data('test', dictionary)

train_x = train_x_pos + train_x_neu + train_x_neg
train_y = [1] * len(train_x_pos) + [0] * len(train_x_neu) + [-1] * len(train_x_neg)

test_x = test_x_pos + test_x_neu + test_x_neg
test_y = [1] * len(test_x_pos) + [0] * len(test_x_neu) + [-1] * len(test_x_neg)
```

Are my modifications to **train_y** and **test_y** correct?

Assuming they are correct, I went ahead and trained this model on my data, and I was successfully able to save new versions of **lstm_model.npz** and **lstm_model.npz.pkl**.

Now, how do I test this model on a new example? Suppose a new, unseen example is the following text:

```
new_example = "I am very happy that I've been able to create a new LSTM sentiment model!"
```

My understanding is that the function **pred_probs** needs to be called, which takes parameters **f_pred_prob**, **prepare_data**, **data**, **iterator** and **verbose=False**. What do I pass in for these parameters? I'm guessing the function call would then be something like:

```
pred_probs(f_pred_prob, prepare_data, data=new_example, iterator, verbose=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After turning this over for weeks I finally got a working model. It turns out my modifications to main() in **imdb_preprocess.py** were almost correct, the relevant lines are:

```
train_y = [2] * len(train_x_pos) + [1] * len(train_x_neu) + [0] * len(train_x_neg)
test_y = [2] * len(test_x_pos) + [1] * len(test_x_neu) + [0] * len(test_x_neg)
```

As for how to classify a new example, I had the right idea:

```
new_example_pair = (new_example, 0)
pred_probs(f_pred_prob, prepare_data, new_example_pair, iterator, verbose=False)
```

**pred_probs** should be modified to accommodate three classes, and changing it properly should return a probability value for each possible class.